# How to properly unbind a window event in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So in my controller (for now, probably moving to a directive soon) I have a line of code that uses jQuery to bind to the scroll event on the window. It then executes a function that does some checks to see if it should highlight some elements.

The problem is, I want to properly unbind this event when the page is changed and the controller is gone. What is the proper way of unbinding events in angular?

(I know about jQuery's `.off()` method, I'm just wanting to know when and where I should place that call.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides a `$destroy` event when a scope is being destroyed.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    //jQuery.off
});
```

But, yes as you said, this should move into a directive, and angular also provides a `$destroy` method on html elements.

Comment: there is a scope for directives? because I'm binding to window, not an element

Comment: @LordZardeck Yes there is scope in directives, which is why the controller and link functions both take a scope as a parameter. However for directives you'd be better off doing `element.on('$destroy', ...);`

Comment: @LordZardeck I just noticed you were binding to the window event, in which case yeah you wouldn't use the `element.on('$destroy')` approach, but you could still use the `scope.$on('$destroy')` approach